# Tail recursion for a function

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a homework problem that gives a recursive function and I have to implement it using tail-recursion. The function is

f(0) = 1
f(n) = 1+2*f(n-1)

I am not the best at tail-recursion and i tried to look up examples but all i find are examples witht the fibonacci sequence and it doesnt help much.

All i really have is

```
def f(n,s=1):
    if n == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return f(n-1, "i dont know what to put here")
```

I understand that tail recursion basically computes the function every call through i just dont know how to implement it.

Edit: I made a typo f(n) is supposed to be 1 + 2*f(n-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tail recursion, you track the sum as you go:

```
$ cat foo.py 
import sys

def f(n,s=1):
    if n == 0:
        return s
    return f(n-1, 1+2*s)

r = int(sys.argv[1])
print(f(r))
```

Output:

```
$ seq 0 10 | xargs -I% python foo.py %
1
3
7
15
31
63
127
255
511
1023
2047
```